# From a neuroscientific point of view does internet gaming disorder have the same effect on the brain as porn addiction?

Tags: neuroscience, addiction

[Wang, et al. (2015)](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/25852507/) proved that among people with internet gaming disorder GMV (Gray Matter Volume) of the bilateral anterior cingulate cortex (ACC), precuneus, supplementary motor area (SMA), superior parietal cortex, left dorsal lateral prefrontal cortex (DLPFC), left insula, and bilateral cerebellum decreased in the IGD participants compared with healthy controls. Is it the same with internet porn addicts?

### References

Wang, H., Jin, C., Yuan, K., Shakir, T. M., Mao, C., Niu, X., Niu, C., Guo, L., & Zhang, M. (2015). The alteration of gray matter volume and cognitive control in adolescents with internet gaming disorder. *Frontiers in behavioral neuroscience, 9*, 64. https://doi.org/10.3389/fnbeh.2015.00064

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. You said, *"It is proven that..."* Can you please provide reference information for the study/studies which prove this?

Comment: Yeah sure, I added the link. Sorry.

Comment: What makes you ask this question specifically? I.e., why porn addiction specifically, and not "train enthusiasts" or any other thing?

Comment: @StevenJeuris Well, they are both internet addictions. so I assumed that they are more closely related.

Comment: I should have stated internet porn addiction instead of just porn addiction